# What is Esc actually for?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

I have always thought of the Esc key as a "stop, get me out" button.
The main cases where I would like to use it is for:

Stopping scripts and apps when slowing down computer.
Stopping loading of pages.
Getting out of full-screen.

None of these seem to work though.
This is of concern to me now because I have Windows 8 installed and the new UI often means apps with no clear menu. I know there are probably gestures, mouse actions and keyboard shortcuts to achieve what I want, but isn't the concept of escaping something important?
What is the meaning and importance of Esc?

Answer (score 1):

Escape means whatever the developer of the program wanted it to mean. Microsoft does [publish guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about keyboard input for developers but if the developer did not decide to follow those guidelines there is no telling what the button will do for a individual program.

One thing you can do is use a program like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap the Esc key to perform any action you want. All you need to do is write up a simple script and you can have it execute every time you press Esc.